# multiple lookups in query with possible NULL values

Tags: mysql

Here's what I have and here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
teams TABLE
TeamID Season     Coach1     Coach2
1      2011       35         22
2      2011       27
3      2012       11
4      2013       22         13

staff TABLE
StaffID     Nickname
11          Bob
13          Rick
22          Mary
27          Steve
35          Joe

desired OUTPUT:
TeamID Season   c1       c2
1      2011     Joe      Mary
2      2011     Steve
3      2012     Bob
4      2013     Mary     Rick
```

Here's my current MYSQL query:

```
SELECT gt.TeamID, gt.Season, gt.Coach1, c1.Nickname c1Nickname, gt.Coach2, c2.Nickname c2Nickname
FROM gladiator_teams as gt, staff as c1, staff as c2
WHERE gt.Coach1=c1.StaffID AND gt.Coach2=c2.StaffID
```

This returns:

```
TeamID Season   c1       c2
1      2011     Joe      Mary
4      2013     Mary     Rick
```

I can't figure out how to modify the query to return rows that have NULL values for Coach 2. I suppose I need an IFNULL function to go somewhere, but I can't figure out where exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use left JOIN

```
SELECT 
   gt.TeamID
 , gt.Season
 , gt.Coach1
 , c1.Nickname c1Nickname
 , gt.Coach2
 , c2.Nickname c2Nickname
FROM gladiator_teams as gt
LEFT JOIN staff as c1  gt.Coach1=c1.StaffID
LEFT JOIN staff as c2 gt.Coach2=c2.StaffID
```